# How to deserialize json to specified object at run time in c#

Tags: c#, json

I can get two types of json at run time

1

```
{ "op":"put_message",
  "args":"create_time":1386590144.372,
  "user_ids":["jin.raj1381386731048.15195712",
              "shami.gulug1378102436530.59079906",
              "sweth.pilli1378100716736.58912086",
              "sai_n.gavar1378384157577.59878517"],
  "groups":[]
}
```

2

```
{
  "op":"put_message",
  "args":"create_time":1386590144.372,
  "user_ids":"jin.raj1381386731048.15195712",
  "groups":[]
}
```

`user_ids` can be `List<string>` or only `string`..
So how can i deserialize that based on user_ids using JsonConvert libray?

Comment: `http://james.newtonking.com/json` we can use it ..

Comment: Can you change the JSON format to always return an array (potentially only holding a single element)?

Comment: As @UfukHacıoğulları said, this `"args":"create_time":1386590144.372` isn't valid JSON. Get valid JSON first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)